# C++ NetBeans std::array not usable

Tags: c++, netbeans, std, mingw32

I am using MinGW C++ compiler in a statically linked project with NetBeans.

I am trying to use `std::array` but it seems that when I `#include <array>` NetBeans doesn't recognize it. When I write `std::` a list of possibilities unfolds, but the array struct is nowhere to be found.

When I Ctrl+Click the `<array>` standard library header, it opens (thus, it is found by the IDE)... but the declarations appear in grey for some reason...

[image: #include <array>]
---------------->
If I remove the define guards (alias #ifndef -- #endif) it works fine, but... why do I have to change this header to make it work? Am I missing something? I am using "x86_64-w64-mingw32" to compile.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your code compile? Is this just a _NetBeans_ quirk?

Comment: What version of the mingw compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` macro is not defined.

You can activate that (partial C++11 support) with the `-std=c++0x` compiler option.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have a macro defined.  This stuff is still very new to C++ standard.

Comment: Thank you, this was it. I chose the other answer because it was more specific to my problem.